# POST a very large xml to url using LWP Perl

Tags: xml, perl, post, lwp

I have a very large xml which i am trying to pass to a Spark on a particular port. Following is the code i am using to submit the xml using POST request.

```
my $_fileName = "/home/temp/UTC+08_20180406_1414000_xyz";
open (XMLFILE, $_fileName);
    while (<XMLFILE>) {
        $_xml.=$_;
    }
    close (XMLFILE);

my $_url="http://localhost:8100/request/UTC+08_20180406_1414000_xyz";
my $curl = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $curl->post($_url, 'Content' => $_xml, 'Content-type'=>'text/xml' );
if ($response->is_success) 
{
     print("new job created (requestId: $_requestId)\n");
     return &checkXMLStatus($response->decoded_content);
}
else 
{
     print("Job can't be processed: ".$response->status_line);
     return ("StatusRejected", $response->status_line, 0);
}
```

When the xml is small, then there is no issues. But when i submit a very large xml file say more than 100000 lines, then the request times out with the following error:

"500 read timeout" exactly after 180 seconds.
I checked CPAN page of LWP where there is a default timeout of 180.

Is it possible to increase the timeout. And is there any limitation of not being able to send a very large xml file using POST request using LWP??

Comment: What would be the number of bytes in such a 100,000-line XML file? I can't imagine it being more than a couple of MB.

Comment: Why are you readying the xml line by line like that? Would it not be simpler to: `my $xml = do { local $/; <XMLFILE>};` and read it all in one go?

Comment: @Borodin: its 10 - 50 MB

Comment: Why have you named an `LWP::UserAgent` object `$curl`?

Comment: yeah, $ua instead of $curl would be a better choice I think.

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page of [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/libwww-perl-6.33/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#new), the parameter is called `timeout` and can be set via an `options` hash, so to set the timeout, say to 300, the line creating the user agent should read:

`my $curl = LWP::UserAgent->new( { timeout => 300 } );`

Answer (score 1):

Those monks writes about timeout on http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=896468

Also I would check if the receiver can handle gzip-compressed data and if so use `gzip` to send only perhaps 5-10% the original number of bytes. The time savings could be similar.

```
open my $FH, "gzip < $_filename |" or die;
binmode($FH);
$_xml=do{local$/;<$FH>};
...
my $response = $curl->post( $_url,
                            'Content' => $_xml,
                            'Content-Encoding'=>'gzip',
                            'Content-Type'=>'text/xml' );
```

If the receiver can take `multipart/form-data` I would also check out:

```
system(qq(
  gzip < $_filename | curl -F"file=@-;type=text/xml;filename=n.xml" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" $_url
));
```

...with `file=` and `filename=` changed into what the receiver needs.